# Playing the same number at loto game

Tags: probability

A simple question that was already asked but I didn't understand the modelisation.
If I play always the same number at the loto, it does really look like a binomial distribution, like a die that I throw and I want to get at least a  6. In the case of the die, if I bet on a 6 each time, my probability of getting at least a 6 increases at each game. It becomes for instance $1- (\frac {5}{6})^2$
the second time I throw it.
So why shouldn't it increase at the loto game, if I play the same numbers and there is no bias?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. *What* looks like a binomial distribution? Why do you say your probability of winning the dice game increases each game? It is $1/6$ every time.

Comment: I made my question more precise. Obviously the probability at each game does not change.

Answer (score 1):

The probability in lotto does increase the same way.  As you say, if you roll dice $n$ times trying to get a $6$ your chance of at least one success is $1-(\frac 56)^n$.  If you play a lotto with $10^6$ possible outcomes $n$ times the chance of at least one success is $1-(\frac{999,999}{1,000,000})^n$.  For small $n$ this is about $\frac n{1,000,000}$, so it increases linearly with $n$.

Comment: Ok. So it shoud be a good strategy to play always the sane number?

Comment: @Nestor The strategy is *exactly* so good as playing a random number each time. The same concerns the throwing of dice.

Comment: Singleplayer, yes, but in a scenario with many players and a fixed pool, there is a slight benefit in choosing numbers that nobody else chooses, because otherwise you might need to share the jackpot.

Comment: Is  there any explanation of this?  With the binomial distribution, it seems at first look that it's  better not to change because the probability is griwing.

Comment: Each roll is independent.  In the dice case as well, the $1-(\frac 56)^n$ applies whether you choose the same number each time or change the number you are looking for each time.  The point is that you have $\frac 56$ chance of not getting the number you asked for, regardless of what it is.  To not get your number every time for $n$ throws the chance is then $(\frac 56)^n$  The lotto case is the same but with a lower chance of success.

Comment: Thanks very much Ross. I never thought that changing the number for the dice does not change the probability obtained by Bernoulli's distribution.